# C type casting doubts when type are converted many times here and there

Tags: c, casting

What is this type casting doing?

```
ph = (struct Proghdr *)((uint8_t *) ELFHDR + ELFHDR->e_phoff);
```

Here, `ELFHDR` is already defined as `#define ELFHDR ((struct Elf *) 0x10000)`.

I want to ask: At the end, the value in `ph` will be `(struct Proghdr *)` then what is the need for the `(uint8_t *)`?

I will be grateful if someone solves my problem related to type-casting.

Comment: So that the pointer arithmetic works correctly when `ELFHDR->e_phoff` is a number of bytes. It works in *units of the object type.*

Comment: I think it needs to be `char *`, not `uint8_t *`, for this to be standard-compliant?

Comment: @ikegami Possibly. But, if `uint8_t` is defined, it will surely be the smallest unit possible, which will be 1 byte, is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember the equivalence `p[i] == *( p + i )`.

Given pointer `p` and integer `i`, `p + i` advances pointer `p` by `i` times the size of `*p`.

For example, you see `p` advanced by 8 times the time size of a `uint32_t` in the following:

```c
uint32_t a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
uint32_t *p = a;
p = p + 8;
printf( "%" PRIu32 "\n", *p );  // 8
```

So if you wanted to advance the pointer by `i` *bytes*, you'd need a pointer to a byte (`char`).

```c
uint32_t a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
uint32_t *p = a;
p = (uint32_t *)( (char *)p + 8 );
printf( "%" PRIu32 "\n", *p );  // 2
```

`uint8_t` is used as an equivalent of `char` in the snippet you posted.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sPxYEf59q) on Compile Explorer

Comment: Thanks a lot all, but if you can solve one more doubt.'p = (uint32_t *)( (char *)p + 8 );'.When p is already uint32 pointer than why (char*)p+8 is again converted into uint32

Comment: @OSdev first the pointer is cast to `char*` so that `8 * sizeof(char*)` is added (not `8 * sizeof(uint32_t)` and then the resulting `char*` is converted back to the original `uint32_t*`.

Comment: Was very much helpful. Hope you will be happy to solve my other doubts.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithmetic in C is performed in units whose size is that of the pointed-to type. So, for example, if `p` is a pointer to a `double`, then `p = p + 1` will add the size (in bytes) of a `double` to the address stored in `p`.

In your case, the `e_phoff` member of the pointed-to structure contains a **byte** offset for some particular data; however, simply adding that value to the `ELFHDR` pointer itself (which is of `Elf*` type) would add that value multiplied by the size of the `Elf` structure. So, in order to properly use that byte offset, the pointer is first cast to a `uint8_t*`, so that any pointer arithmetic is performed in terms of raw (single) bytes.

Comment: Than wht will be the size of pointers of struct type

Comment: Pointers are (almost always) all the same size as each other (depending on the address system of the platform). What changes is how arithmetic is done on them. For a pointer-to-structure, the size of the "base unit" will be the size (in bytes) of the structure.

Comment: Sorry my question was not that.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking. Is it a follow-up question, or do you need clarification of something in my answer? I'll try, either way.

Comment: @OSdev After the byte-based addition has been done, you're left with a `char*` pointer. You now need to cast that again to get the right sort of pointer to use in subsequent operations.